# How to generate a contingency table with counts using pandas?

Tags: pandas, crosstab, contingency

Let's say I have data like this:

```
+-------+--------+--------------+--------+--------------+
| index | used_x | clicked_in_x | used_y | clicked_in_y |
+-------+--------+--------------+--------+--------------+
|     1 | True   | False        | True   | True         |
|     2 | False  | False        | True   | False        |
|     3 | True   | True         | False  | False        |
+-------+--------+--------------+--------+--------------+
```

And I would like to generate a contingency table using using pandas that shows a table like:

```
+--------+----------------+----------------+
|        | clicked_from_x | clicked_from_y |
+--------+----------------+----------------+
| used_x |             40 |              3 |
| used_y |              2 |             10 |
+--------+----------------+----------------+
```

What would be the best way to achieve this? So far I've tried the following using the `crosstab` method:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

size = 20

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'used_x': np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=size),
    'clicked_from_x': np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=size),
    'used_y':  np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=size),
    'clicked_from_y':  np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=size),
})

pd.crosstab([df['used_x'], df['used_y']], [df['clicked_from_x'], df['clicked_from_y']],  margins=False)
```

Which yields:

[image]

But this is pretty hard to make sense of and not the representation I'd hoped for. Does anyone know how to get my desired outcome, or perhaps an equivalent strategy using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll be using the almighty `dot` product subroutine here.

```
i = df.filter(like='clicked')
j = df.filter(like='used')

j.astype(int).T.dot(i)

        clicked_from_x  clicked_from_y
used_x               6               5
used_y               6               6
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it easy/possible to illustrate how to add 1) margins or 2) transform to percentages?

Comment: @fraxture You can do something like: `result = result / result.sum(axis=1)`, does that help?

Comment: @coldspeed actually that division above gives me a bunch of `NaN`s and duplicates the rows as columns..

Comment: @fraxture Last try: `result = result / result.sum(axis=1).values`

Comment: I wonder if there is in fact a way to do this with Pandas's `crosstab` function...

Comment: @fraxture can't say for sure. Is there something about crosstab that dot doesn't give you?

Comment: @coldsleed just gives you margin counts easily.

Comment: @fraxture you know, you could just compute the margin yourself. The complexity of determining the specific arguments to the crosstab query aren't worth the effort IMO.

Comment: I hear you. Actually, what I'd really love an explanation of is why the dot fn works here, i.e. what kind of manipulation makes this work, what mathematical principles are at play...

Comment: @fraxture No problem. Dot is a wonderful function, I'm using it to abuse the hell out of your input. First, understand what a dot product is. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication). Trace its working to see what it does. I take advantage of the fact that True==1  and False == 0, so when you multiply. True x True == True (or 1), True x False = False (or 0), and False x False = False (or 0). Furthermore, summing these products give me the cooccurrence counts (1 + 0 + 1 + ...), giving your final result. Does this make sense?

Comment: Finally, the dot product is _very fast_, having been implemented in C/Fortran, and is vectorised to make full use of your compute power. It's a marvel of software engineering, especially high performance computing.